# Is it necessary to sign every blackberry application even if i have to just test it on blackberry real device?

Tags: eclipse, blackberry

I had only packaged my application for `Blackberry` using `ripple`, but didn't sign that. But when I tried to run the application on my device, it is throwing an error message like `Module Mybbapp attempts to access a secure API` and the application terminates.

I am using `Ripple` version `0.9.16` and `Blackberry SDK 2.3.1.5` using `Eclipse`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using signed API in your code, then you need to sign your application, before installing it on an actual device. Unsigned app that uses signed API will work only on simulator, but won't work on an actual device.

Apply for signing keys here: http://www.blackberry.com/go/codesigning

You will receive an email with attached signing keys. Follow the instructions in the received email to install these keys and use them to sign your application.